# SMS INBOX - LISTVIEW

Tags: android

Hello i am trying to create SMS aplication witch shows me SMS Inbox in ListView.But if i open this aplication there is no action.I can see only black screen with name of aplication :( .Can somebody check my source code and tell me where is the problem? Thank you.

There is source code:

```
package sms.five;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Smsfive extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, ListView messages) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        List<String> msgList = getSMS();

        for(int i = 0; i<msgList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(msgList.get(i));
       }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main, msgList); 
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
       {
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
         SmsManager m = SmsManager.getDefault();
         String destinationNumber=(String) ((TextView)view).getText();              
         m.sendTextMessage(destinationNumber, null, destinationNumber, null, null);

       }          
         });
       }

    public List<String> getSMS() {      
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = null;
        try{
            c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            for (boolean hasData = c.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = c.moveToNext()) {
                final String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
                final String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                list.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     c.close(); 
     return list;
    }
}
```

XML File(main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="sms.five"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Smsfive"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you verify that `getSMS()` returns something?

Comment: There is no SMS inbox in the Android OS.

Comment: No Sms inbox? So how can i acess delivered  sms?

Comment: @Nanne: I think it add to ListView(list) information about sms.But i am not sure..

Comment: There is another problem .. i found this error: [2011-02-04 15:04:56 - Sms5] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your `getSMS()` is not returning anything. You can check this by adding some debugging code after this line:

```
List<String> msgList = getSMS();
```

Something like

```
Log.d("yourTag","number of items: ".msgList->size());
```

It seems that it doesn't return anything. You might start by debugging that particular function: are there any exceptions caught? add some logging to see that. Maybe you didn't add the correct line in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Or something else goes wrong in that function. Did you write it yourself, or was it a copy?

Comment: Yes,you'r right that is not returning anything. Do you now how i can change it?

Comment: I added corect line in my manifest.It is copy but little bit edited...I am beginner in android.. I am just learning

Comment: But there is some error i have already written it : ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: Well, that means that you've deployed your apk to your virtual android, but it is not changed: the system is warning you that it did not re-install the apk, but instead loaded the current activity. If it keeps doing that even though you've changed code, just restart them.

Comment: Yes but i am trying apps on my HTC desire but there is same problem i can see only black screen with name of my app :( that getSMS() is not returning anything but i dont know how i can fix it.Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That would be basic debuggin? You might start using with adding logs where you have the `e.printStackTrace();`. Check out what happens there, are you getting an exception? if so, try to figure out what it is, and why you are getting it. Are you iterating over anything at all? Maybe add a log to that `for` part, and check if that does anything. Also, use the debug function in eclipse to step trought your code.

Answer (score 0):

remove `c.close()` in your getSMS method.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is line " ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.main, msgList); "

argument R.layout.main is false , it's layout item custom by you Or android built example like android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

=> change R.layout.main - > android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1  . succsess 100 %