# Sms Inbox - ListView

Tags: android

Hello i am trying to create aplication witch shows me sms in ListView but i dont know how i can fill listview by datas.I tried do that but it doesn't work.Can you check my source code and give me some resolution? Thanks

Source code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Mynewtwo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        List<String> msgList = getSMS();


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main, msgList); 
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public List<String> getSMS(){
         List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                   String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                   String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                  sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);  

              }
            return sms;

        }
```

}

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you asking the same question 3 times? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905736/sms-inbox-textview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897004/sms-inbox-listview

Comment: this is another source code and they are talking me i must make new topic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never fill any data to your `ListView` because the mistake you have made is here:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main, msgList);
```

in this you are telling that items of the `msgList` object will be shown on the `R.layout.main` file and your file doesn't contain any `TextView` or other layout object.

So use like this:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simple_list_item_1,msgList);
```

Comment: Did you mean android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Comment: @Adam : I would recommend that you must have to read [this article](http://mainerrors.blogspot.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-and-how-not-to-suck-at.html). and also you should mark the answers as accepted.

Comment: how can i  mark the answers?=D i looked for it but i didn't find it.

Comment: On the left side of an answer you can find an **Right Mark** . You have to tick that Option and it will be highlighted as a green. And you have done it.